# Sequelize query SELECT * FROM Table only returning one row

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm currently using PostgreSQL and Sequelize.js to query some data. When I'm using sequelize.query(), it only returns one row data but when I enter it through pgAdmin it works as expected.

Here is the code I use in sequelize.query().

```
   SELECT table2.student_id,
          s.canvasser_name,
          l.level_name,
          table2.total_score
   FROM (SELECT table1.student_id,
                sum(table1.max_score) total_score
         FROM (SELECT sq.student_id,
               max(sq.score) max_score
               FROM public.student_quiz sq
               GROUP BY sq.quiz_id, sq.student_id) table1
         GROUP BY table1.student_id) table2
   INNER JOIN public.student s
           ON s.id = table2.student_id
   INNER JOIN public.level l
           ON l.id = s.level_id
   ORDER BY table2.total_score DESC
   LIMIT 10;
```

And here is the nodejs code

```
const getRank = (option, logs = {}) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    let { offset, limit } = option;
    if (!limit) limit = 10;
    const result = await sequelize.query(
      `SELECT table2.student_id,
              s.canvasser_name,
              l.level_name,
              table2.total_score
       FROM (SELECT table1.student_id,
                    sum(table1.max_score) total_score
             FROM (SELECT sq.student_id,
                   max(sq.score) max_score
                   FROM public.student_quiz sq
                   GROUP BY sq.quiz_id, sq.student_id) table1
             GROUP BY table1.student_id) table2
       INNER JOIN public.student s
               ON s.id = table2.student_id
       INNER JOIN public.level l
               ON l.id = s.level_id
       ORDER BY table2.total_score DESC
       LIMIT 10;`,
      { plain: true }
    );

    return resolve(result);
  } catch (error) {
    let customErr = error;
    if (!error.code) customErr = Helpers.customErrCode(error, null, undefinedError);
    logger.error(logs);
    return reject(customErr);
  }
});
```

And here is the code that consume the function above

```
const getRankController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { offset, limit } = req.query;
    const result = await getRank({ offset, limit });

    if (result.length < 1) {
      return Helpers.response(res, {
        success: false,
        message: 'cannot get score list'
      }, 404);
    }

    return Helpers.response(res, {
      success: true,
      result
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return Helpers.error(res, error);
  }
};
```

In the meantime, I'm trying another approach using the sequelize built in function, here is the code.

```
const getRank = (
  option,
  logs = {}
) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
    let { offset, limit } = option;
    if (!limit) limit = 10;
    const result2 = await StudentQuiz.findAll({
      attributes: ['studentId', [sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('score'))), 'totalPrice'], 'quizId'],
      group: 'studentId',
      include: [
        {
          model: Student,
          include: [{
            model: Level
          }],
        },
      ],
      offset,
      limit
    });
    
    return resolve(result2);
  } catch (error) {
    let customErr = error;
    if (!error.code) customErr = Helpers.customErrCode(error, null, undefinedError);
    logger.error(logs);
    return reject(customErr);
  }
});
```

This one does not work since it is nested function, I kinda don't get it how to reproduce it.

I've tried to do some simple query like SELECT * FROM table and it returns one row, and then I've found out that I need to add "public" to table name so it became SELECT * FROM public.table and it works out. Well, until I'm trying the code in the second code block.

Any answer or advice will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Seems to be your tables are in `Public` schema and so it works where you select the table with schema name

Comment: @JimMacaulay I see, so any idea why it only returns one row. I mean I get it if it returns none, but why does it only returns one?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the sequelize code.  A good idea to add it to the question.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson Nice call, I've updated it. Please have a look.

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint at `return resolve(result);` and look what is `result` contents?

Comment: @Anatoly as per your suggestion, I just did and it is returning one row from the query operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need to indicate a query type and remove `plain: true` option like this:

```
const result = await sequelize.query(
      `SELECT table2.student_id,
              s.canvasser_name,
              l.level_name,
              table2.total_score
       FROM (SELECT table1.student_id,
                    sum(table1.max_score) total_score
             FROM (SELECT sq.student_id,
                   max(sq.score) max_score
                   FROM public.student_quiz sq
                   GROUP BY sq.quiz_id, sq.student_id) table1
             GROUP BY table1.student_id) table2
       INNER JOIN public.student s
               ON s.id = table2.student_id
       INNER JOIN public.level l
               ON l.id = s.level_id
       ORDER BY table2.total_score DESC
       LIMIT 10;`,
      { 
        type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
      }
    );
```

From Sequelize documentation:

```
options.plain - Sets the query type to SELECT and return a single row
```

Comment: added it, still no luck here.

Comment: Man, you will not believe what I've been through looking for this answer. Thank you very much, you are the best.

Answer (score 0):

For those still having issues with this, what worked for me was to use

> ```
>     type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW
> ```

instead of

> ```
>      type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
> ```

Full query:

```
const result = await sequelize.query(
      `SELECT table2.student_id,
              s.canvasser_name,
              l.level_name,
              table2.total_score
       FROM (SELECT table1.student_id,
                    sum(table1.max_score) total_score
             FROM (SELECT sq.student_id,
                   max(sq.score) max_score
                   FROM public.student_quiz sq
                   GROUP BY sq.quiz_id, sq.student_id) table1
             GROUP BY table1.student_id) table2
       INNER JOIN public.student s
               ON s.id = table2.student_id
       INNER JOIN public.level l
               ON l.id = s.level_id
       ORDER BY table2.total_score DESC
       LIMIT 10;`,
      { 
        type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW
      }
    );
```